# In jpeg image compression, what is the effect of increasing block size on the values of DCT coefficients statistically?

Tags: jpeg, distribution, dct

For example increasing block size from 8x8 to 16x16.
I expect the coefficients will decrease because there will be an averaging between the corresponding coefficients for the merged blocks ( in the above example: 4 blocks of 8x8 composes 1 block of 16x16 ). if they really decrease , does the low frequencies decrease more faster? can we say that the information will be pushed toward the high frequency coefficients if they decrease slower? and this will reduce the image quality because the quantization is higher in the high frequency area? can I say that the quantization error is higher for larger blocks because there will be more coefficients then multiple quantization errors for one pixel? I feel the answer need some mathematics. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Daala frequency-domain block resizing, it seems they're not directly comparable and the relationship is somewhat complicated:

[https://people.xiph.org/~xiphmont/demo/daala/demo3.shtml](https://people.xiph.org/%7Exiphmont/demo/daala/demo3.shtml)

However, the overall behavior is similar and in terms of compression it doesn't change much, besides obvious reduction in number of block edges in low quality range:

https://libjpeg-turbo.org/About/SmartScale-Lossy